# How do I get curl or wget working for graph.facebook.com/..?

Tags: facebook, bash, facebook-graph-api, curl, wget

When I enter this in my Browser:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/COMMENTID/comments?limit=5000&access_token=MyAcesstoken
```

..everything is fine and i get all what i want, BUT
when i use this with **curl** or **wget** in my terminal on ubuntu.. I just get everytime this:

```
{"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104,
```

When is use **wget** I get a bad request and it doesnt work, too.

Please, help me! I cant figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Make double sure you are passing a valid parameter to `access_token`. Try replacing curl or wget with `echo` to check if the correct variable substitution is taking place.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure access token is correct and you are using curl function as intended. I have tested the below code with a valid access token and it is giving me answer. May this help you as well.

```
$accessToken = 'YourValidAccessToken';
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/505995689525544_506415109483602/comments?limit=5000&access_token=$accessToken";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$arr = json_decode($result,true);
print_r($arr);
```